# how to type expressJS action?

Tags: typescript, express, types

so i have a router

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { sign_up } from "../controllers/users.controller";
import { validateRequest } from "zod-express";
import { UsersSignUpBody } from "../models/users";

export const usersRouter = Router();

usersRouter.post("/sign_up", validateRequest({ body: UsersSignUpBody }), sign_up);
```

and a controller with sign_up action

```
export async function sign_up(req: TypedRequestBody<typeof UsersSignUpBody>, res: Response) {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const password = req.body.password;

    const user = await createUser({name, password}); ///prisma used here

    return res.json({
        attributes: user,
        dataType: 'user'
    });
}
```

My question is: How do I create a type for an action which responds using `Response` object from `Express.js`?

EDIT

i notice i can just type it as `Promise<Response>` but thats not very specific, can i somehow include the `User` attributes and the attributes that im manually passing into the `json` method?

Comment: Do you mean you want a return type of the `sign_up` function?

Comment: yes! one that would help 'validate' if what i return with res.json() is correct